# Implementing horizontal scrollbar for specific column of datagrid in flex

Tags: apache-flex, datagrid, horizontal-scrolling

How to implement horizontal scrollbar for specific column of datagrid in flex? Say I have a column whose rows are showing particular rendered graphics component. If it exceeds column width then how can I set up scrollbar for that particular column? If I set horizontalScrollPolicy="on" then it sets horizontal scrollbar for whole datagrid. I want that for particular column.Can this be done?

Answer (score 0):

You have not specified which version of the datagrid component you use (mx or spark). Here are examples for both of them. I have used a simple text as content of the scrolled column. One can use such approach whatever the content is.

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
           xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
           xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" minWidth="955" minHeight="600">
<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        import mx.collections.ArrayCollection;

        [Bindable]private var collection:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection([
            {field01:"field01", content:"your content your content your content your content", field02:"field02"},
            {field01:"field01", content:"your content your content your content your content", field02:"field02"},
            {field01:"field01", content:"your content your content your content your content", field02:"field02"}
        ]);
    ]]>
</fx:Script>

<s:VGroup x="10" y="10">

    <!-- the new Spark DataGrid -->

    <s:DataGrid 
        width="300" height="180" 
        rowHeight="50" 
        dataProvider="{collection}">

        <s:columns>
            <s:ArrayList>   
                <s:GridColumn dataField="field01" headerText="Field 1"/>
                <s:GridColumn dataField="content" headerText="Content" width="100">
                    <s:itemRenderer>
                        <fx:Component>
                            <s:GridItemRenderer>
                                <s:Scroller width="100%" height="100%">
                                    <s:HGroup width="100%" height="100%" verticalAlign="middle">
                                        <s:Label text="{data.content}" width="300"/>
                                    </s:HGroup>
                                </s:Scroller>

                            </s:GridItemRenderer>
                        </fx:Component>
                    </s:itemRenderer>
                </s:GridColumn>
                <s:GridColumn dataField="field02" headerText="Field 2" width="100"/>
            </s:ArrayList>                  
        </s:columns>                
    </s:DataGrid>

    <!-- the old MX DataGrid -->
    <mx:DataGrid
        width="300" height="180" 
        rowHeight="50" 
        dataProvider="{collection}">
        <mx:columns>
            <mx:DataGridColumn dataField="field01" headerText="Field 1" width="100"/>

            <mx:DataGridColumn dataField="content" headerText="Content" width="100">
                <mx:itemRenderer>
                    <fx:Component>
                        <mx:HBox width="100%" >
                            <mx:Label text="{data.content}"/>
                        </mx:HBox>
                    </fx:Component>
                </mx:itemRenderer> 
            </mx:DataGridColumn>

            <mx:DataGridColumn dataField="field02" headerText="Field 2" width="100"/>
        </mx:columns>

    </mx:DataGrid>
</s:VGroup>

</s:Application>
```

**//EDIT**

Here is what I meaned by "faked approach":

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
           xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
           xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" minWidth="955" minHeight="600">
<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        import mx.collections.ArrayCollection;

        [Bindable]private var collection:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection([
            {field01:"field01", content:"your content your content your content your content", field02:"field02"},
            {field01:"field01", content:"your content your content your content your content", field02:"field02"},
            {field01:"field01", content:"your content your content your content your content", field02:"field02"}
        ]);

        [Bindable]public var currentScrollPosition:int = 0;
    ]]>
</fx:Script>

<s:VGroup x="10" y="10">
    <mx:DataGrid
        width="300" height="180" 
        rowHeight="50" 
        dataProvider="{collection}">
        <mx:columns>
            <mx:DataGridColumn dataField="field01" headerText="Field 1" width="100"/>

            <mx:DataGridColumn dataField="content" headerText="Content" width="100">
                <mx:itemRenderer>
                    <fx:Component>

                        <mx:HBox width="100%" horizontalScrollPolicy="off">
                            <mx:HBox id="hbMove" x="{-outerDocument.currentScrollPosition}" width="300">
                                <mx:Label text="{data.content}"/>   
                            </mx:HBox>
                        </mx:HBox>

                    </fx:Component>
                </mx:itemRenderer> 
            </mx:DataGridColumn>

            <mx:DataGridColumn dataField="field02" headerText="Field 2" width="100"/>
        </mx:columns>

    </mx:DataGrid>

    <mx:HBox horizontalGap="0">
        <s:Spacer width="100"/>
        <mx:HScrollBar id="sbMover" width="100" minScrollPosition="0" maxScrollPosition="300" scroll="{currentScrollPosition = sbMover.scrollPosition}"/>
    </mx:HBox>

</s:VGroup>

</s:Application>
```

Comment: Thanks Anton !! Can you please tell me if this can be done as one scroller on one whole column instead of each row of the column?

Comment: I think it is impossible. The cells of one column are same objects of one specific class. So they should look in one common way. In this case I don't know any place in the data grid where your feature can be implemented. May be you can fake the behaviour by using an external scrollbar and shifting the column's content according to its value.

Comment: You can see a faked version of the solution in my post.